# Getting update counts for a batch insert/update in ibatis

Tags: jdbc, ibatis, mybatis

Using the latest version of mybatis. Have a mapper and DAO. Doing batch inserts. Its working but I want to know how many rows were inserted. In JDBC I can get the update counts as an int array .. How can I get this in mybatis/ibatis ?

```
Mapper..
@Insert(NEW_ORDER)
int create(final OrderBatch order); // represents one row to insert

DAO...
    public int createOrders(SqlSession session, List<OrderBatch> orders) {
        OrderBatchMapper mapper = session.getMapper(OrderBatchMapper.class);
        for (OrderBatch order : orders) {
     // HOW CAN I GET THE int[] or int of update count?
            i = mapper.create(order);
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using batches, statements are executed when the transaction ends or when flushStatements has been called.

Executing this

```
List<BatchResult> results = session.flushStatements();
```

Should work for you.